# How to build query in React MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, mern

I use the MERN stack and I want to create something like this on the frontend: http://localhost:3000/products?color=0000&sort=latest&category=man etc.
I'm using the redux toolkit and my getProductSlice looks like this:

```
export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  'product/get',
  async ({ page, sort, localValue, colorFilter, categoryFilter }, thunkAPI) => {
    let colorStr = colorFilter.substring(1);
    let url = `/api/v1/products?page=${page}&sort=${sort}&color=${colorStr}&cat=${categoryFilter}`;
    if (localValue) {
      url = url + `&search=${localValue}`;
    }

    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(url);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      const message = error.response.data.msg;
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

Every filter works great, in the backend I return products depending on which filter is applied. I dont know how to build query in frontend and when i enter that url i want to filters to be applied based on url.

Answer (score 0):

To build a query string in the frontend and apply filters based on the query string in the URL, you can do the following:

1 Parse the query string from the URL using the URLSearchParams API:

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

Extract the values of the filters from the query string using the get method of URLSearchParams:

```
const color = searchParams.get('color');
const sort = searchParams.get('sort');
const category = searchParams.get('category');
```

Use the extracted filter values to create a payload object for the getProducts async thunk:

```
const payload = {
  page: 1, // or whatever page you want to start from
  sort,
  localValue: '', // or whatever value you want to use for the localValue filter
  colorFilter: color,
  categoryFilter: category
};
```

Dispatch the getProducts async thunk with the payload object:

```
dispatch(getProducts(payload));
```

This should apply the filters based on the query string in the URL when the getProducts async thunk is dispatched.

Comment: Yes, that's make sense, but i got error: "colorFilter is null"